# Different URL's to the same controller ASP MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to generate a navigation that has 'System' and 'Category' archons or buttons. System and Category are using the same controller. I would like to use `[Route()]` instead of the `Startup` file for routing.

For category archon works great:

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="@value.Controller" asp-action="@Constants.Route.List" asp-route-valueId="@value.ValueId">@value.Value</a>
```

but I dont kow how to use the same controller for 'admin/system/list' instead of admin/categorytype/list, so far I tried:

**1)**

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-route="System" asp-action="@Constants.Route.List" asp-route-valueId="@value.ValueId">@value.Value</a>
```

**2)**

```
<a asp-route="Admin/System/List" asp-route-valueId="@value.ValueId">@value.Value</a>
```

**and at controller**

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Route("Admin/[controller]")]
[Route("Admin/System")]
[Authorize]
public class CategoryTypeController : Controller {}
    [Route("[action]")]
    public ViewResult List(int valueId) {}
```

**3)**

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("SystemValue", new { valueId = value.ValueId })">@value.Value</a>
```

**and at controller**

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Route("Admin/[controller]")]
[Route("Admin/System", Name = "SystemValue")]
[Authorize]
public class CategoryTypeController : Controller {}
    [Route("[action]")]
    public ViewResult List(int valueId) {}
```

none of the above routes generated url that allow me to go to the CategoryType controller and List action by /admin/system/list

I also have `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();` at `Startup` file.

**Edit:**
When I enter the address manually `/admin/system/list` - the router works,
but I can't generate such a url for button or archon to match `/admin/system/list`

as in the attached picture, the archon does not have any url
[image: screenshot of the browser]

<s>**EDIT:**
I found a solution, but I'm not happy with it, it turns out that I do not understand how routing works. For me, the `[Route ()]` attribute is one way to define routs and `app.UseMvc()` is the second way. I had to define routes in two places.</s>

at **Startup.cs**

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SystemValue",
            template: "Admin/System/List/{id?}",
            defaults: new { area = "Admin", controller = "CategoryType", action = "List" });
    });
```

**controller**

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Route("Admin/[controller]")]
[Route("Admin/System", Name = "SystemValue")]
[Authorize]
public class CategoryTypeController : Controller
{}
    [Route("[action]")]
    public ViewResult List(int valueId) {}
```

**view**

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("SystemValue", new { valueId = value.ValueId})">@value.Value</a>
```

I will still be looking for a solution how to do it using only `[Route ("")]`

Comment: Does `[Area("Admin")]
[Route("Admin/[controller]")]
[Route("System", Name = "SystemValue")]
[Authorize]
public class CategoryTypeController : Controller {}
    [Route("List")]
    public ViewResult List(int valueId) {}` work?

Comment: when I enter the address manually
/ admin / system / list - the router works,
but I can not generate such a url for button or archon

I edited main post.

[Route ("List")] to the same thing as [Route ("[action]")]

Comment: `but I can not generate such a url for button` What url *is* it generating?

Comment: I attached a picture - none

Comment: The view in your screenshot. Is it **inside** or **outside** the `Admin` area?

Comment: The view is in inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the routes individualy, you can use named routes, but it is needed to be specified on the method and not on the controller.

```
[Route("/admin/system/list/{id}",name ="SystemList")]
[Route("/admin/category/list/{id}",name ="CategoryList")]
public IActionResult List(int id)
{
...
}
```

you can generate the url for this route as

```
<a asp-route="CategoryList" asp-route-id="@value.ValueId">@value.Value</a>
```

The route system can use the routes declared at the startup or use routes declared by attributes, but they are not mixed, when you sepecify a route attribute at controller level the routes from the startup are ignored.

Comment: thanks!, I've looked through a lot of tutorials about the Route attribute, but none of them had this important detail.